# Storing URL into cookies or session?

Tags: python, django, http

I need a url for using that for a template. Now there are two ways of storing the url and use that again in python I guess...
One is using session to store that URL and get it later whenever we need it...
or 
Second is using cookies to store that URL and get it later..

So which method is more appropriate in terms of security ?
Is there any other method in python which is more better for storing the url and use that later, which is more secure..?

While using cookies somebody can easily change the information I guess, in sessions also somebody can hijack it and make the changes....

Comment: I don't think this is specific to Python. Storing an URL in a cookie or in a session is probably a language agnostic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "session hijacking" means what you think it means. The only thing someone can do with session hijacking is impersonate a user. The actual session data is stored on the back end (eg in the database), so if you don't give the user access to that particular data then they can't change it, whether they're the actual intended user or someone impersonating that user.

So, the upshot of this is, store it in the session.

**Edit after comment** Well, you'd better not allow any information to be sent to your server then, and make your website browse-only.

Seriously, I don't see why "session data" is any less secure than anything else. You are being unreasonably paranoid. If you want to store data, you need to get that data from somewhere, either from a calculation on the server side, or from user submissions. If you can't calculate this specific URL on the server side, it needs to come from the user. And then you need to store it on the server against the particular user. I don't see what else you want to do.

Comment: Still we send the information of session to the server , SO if somebody will impersonate that information at client side then impersonated url will go to server side and at that time if someone can try to inject sql injection or crosssite scripting for my url..than he may can succeed...r8 ?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of security, you should store it in session. If it's in cookie, the client can modify your url to whatever he wants.

Comment: How you'll stop session hijacking than..?? I need a more secure manner as I am using that url later so don;t wanna allow attacker to change that url anyhow..

Comment: how exactly are you going to stop session hijacking anyway?? It depends on the client side security. You can prevent man in the middle attack with ssl encryption, but...

Comment: My aim is to find the best plausible solution for storing the url and use them later, So as We can;t stop session hijacking..so I don;t wanna use session either..thats why I asked this question here..